# Computer crashes after trying to launch Fortnite

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash, gaming

Recently, my computer has been crashing and giving me a blue screen when I try to launch Fortnite.

I think the crash occurs because the game/my account cannot handle when I change what account I am trying to launch with. The only fix I have found that works EVERY TIME is to wait for the next patch to roll out and to NOT change accounts, even on the fortnite.com website. Another way I have found to fix this error is to get the blue screen, to open the launcher, and then to restart my computer multiple times manually, which, in turn, takes a lot of extra time and work.

The error returned when I try to launch Fortnite is a System-Thread-Exception-Not-Handled error and, in half-knowing what runs games, I know that a thread is what actually runs the game which helped me figure out the account glitch. Also, when I immediately close the Epic Games Launcher after getting this glitch, I get a different blue screen message that I can't recall right now.

[Computer Specs and Windows version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwZCk.png)

Also, Fortnite runs with the Easy Anti-Cheat software, which could be the source of the problem.

**EDIT:**

I found the root of this problem: the file is too large to download into the C:/Program_Files folder, which causes it to run weirdly and crash. I don't know of any fix for this besides getting a larger SSD (as of right now it is a 128 GB SSD.

Comment: Hi @sp33dy, you'll need to be more specific in order for your question to be answerable. Specific details of the BSOD you receive, not just the headline 'reason' that's given. What version of Windows 10 you're using may also be useful as more recent versions have had issue with certain "anti-cheat" software in games which may be involved here

Comment: Others: The OP was directed here via https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335049/7872

Comment: @Rob I added specifications about my version of WIndows 10 along with my computer specs. I also added the anti-cheat.

Comment: @Sp33dy Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?